# Views Search Terms not working correctly for taxonomy terms with multiple words

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views

I'm having a bit of an odd issue. I have a Search Terms filter set up on a view and it's not working quite correctly for taxonomy terms in the view.  For example, if one of the Terms is 'International Harvester' and it returns the correct results if I enter *International* or *Harvester* or *"International Harvester"*, but if I put in *International Harvester* without quotes then no results are returned. Any ideas?

using Drupal 7.41, Views 7.x-3.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a bug with the search score feature discussed here https://www.drupal.org/node/1615438.

[This comment](https://www.drupal.org/node/1615438#comment-10289667) details that checking the "Remove search score" checkbox under the **Search: Search Terms** filter fixes that problem.